# Move sematics to move data from one vector to another

Tags: c++, move-semantics

If I have a vector `std::vector<int64_t> oldData`, can I use move semantics to move the data into another vector `std::vector<uint8_t> newData`.

Instead of doing:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> newData(oldData.begin(),oldData.end());
```

Could I do

```
std::vector<uint8_t> newData = std::move(oldData);
```

Will this actually move the data instead of copying it and be more performant?

Comment: You could do `uint8_t* newData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(oldData.data());` if you just want to treat the data in the old vector as an array of bytes.

Comment: Can't be done! note that `oldData` is an array of type `int64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you think carefully about it, it's impossible - you to transform an array of 64 bit integers to an array of 8 bit integers, so you'll have to allocate new space for the new array (8 times smaller) and then copy the least significant 8 bits of every integer in the old array.